# How can I stop $\sqrt{1}$ from being evaluated in a recursively defined sequence?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to list five terms of a sequence $(u_n)$ with $u_1 = 0$ and $u_{n+1}= \sqrt{1 + u_n}$, but I don't want to reduce them. 
My code

```
Clear[u];
u[1] := 0;
u[y_] := Sqrt[1 + u[y - 1]]
A = Table[u[k], {k, 1, 5}]
```

and got
$\left\{0,1,\sqrt{2},\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}}\right\}$

I want $u_3 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1}}$, $u_4 = \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1}} }$ and so on.

How can I stop $\sqrt{1}$ from being evaluated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change

```
u[1] := 1;
```

to

```
u[1] := HoldForm[1];
```

The resulting expression will stay in the form you requested. However, it will not be suitable for computations. It is only usable for display purposes. To make it work for calculations again, apply [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As @LLlAMnYP said, `u[1] := HoldForm@Sqrt[1];` would make the output look a bit nicer.

Comment: Maybe `HoldForm[Sqrt[1]]` to maintain the pattern?

Comment: Yes, that looks nicer!

Answer (score 10):

One can also use `NestList`

```
NestList[Sqrt[1 + #] &, HoldForm@0, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

This in not intended to be an answer, but an extended comment on Szabolcs' answer. I will delete this if he incorporates my remarks into his answer.

I think the code is better written

```
Clear[u]
u[1] = 0;
u[2] = HoldForm[Sqrt[1]];
u[i_?IntegerQ /; i > 1] := u[i] = Sqrt[1 + u[i - 1]]
```

```
Table[u[k], {k, 1, 5}]
```

[image: result]